Django admin inlines that has multilanguage field , TabbedTranslationAdmin does not work correctly
i have a django project, i use django-modeltranslation for translation fields.
it have two model with one-to-many relation and i use django admin with inline for
@admin.register(News)
class NewsAdmin(nested_admin.NestedModelAdmin, TabbedTranslationAdmin):
    inlines = (NewsImageInline,)

and image inline is:
class NewsImageInline(nested_admin.NestedTabularInline,TranslationTabularInline ):
    model = NewsImage
    extra = 1

but in admin, tabularinline not work and show all of fields in one row
